# How to search for GUIDs in Nest.Net in elasticsearch?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Nest which is a .Net client for elasticsearch. I have a problem when searching for GUIDs. As the GUID has "-", elasticsearch is considering as tokens.

Below is the problem I am facing.

I have an entity "Employee" with following properties.

```
   Id : Guid 
   Name : varchar 
   DepartmentId : Guid (E.g cb5d39ee-05f0-4351-baba-8eed6c9111ad)
```

Now I need to get the list of employees who are belongs to particular department. So I will pass the department Id.

As there is a "-" in DepartmentId, elasticsearch is considering as a separator due to which I couldn't get the results.

Employee class

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Analyzer = "keyword")]
    public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the sample code.

```
 class Program
{
    static string indexName = "Elasticsearchsamples".ToLowerInvariant();        

    private static void IndexEmployees()
    {
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        Employee employee;

        var deptId = new Guid("cb5d39ee-05f0-4351-baba-8eed6c9111ad");

        employee = new Employee()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "Raja",
            DepartmentId = deptId
        };
        employees.Add(employee);

        employee = new Employee()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "Ram",
            DepartmentId = deptId
        };
        employees.Add(employee);

        employee = new Employee()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "Guru",
            DepartmentId = Guid.NewGuid()
        };
        employees.Add(employee);

        if (SearchClient.IsConnected())
        {
            SearchClient.ElasticClientInstance.DeleteIndex(indexName);              

            var result = SearchClient.ElasticClientInstance.IndexMany(employees, indexName);
        }
    }

    private static void SearchEmployees()
    {

        var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<Employee>();
        searchDescriptor.Index(indexName);
        var deptId = new Guid("cb5d39ee-05f0-4351-baba-8eed6c9111ad");
        searchDescriptor.Query(qq => qq.Term(x => x.DepartmentId, deptId.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()));
        //searchDescriptor.Query(qq => qq.Term(x => x.Name, "raja"));

        var result = SearchClient.ElasticClientInstance.Search(searchDescriptor);
        Console.WriteLine(result.Total);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;            
        IndexEmployees();
        SearchEmployees();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

On your Employee class you need to tell Elasticsearch to either not analyze the DepartmentId field or use the keyword analyzer. Please note that the documentation for the [keyword](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) analyzer suggests the following:

> An analyzer of type keyword that "tokenizes" an entire stream as a single token. This is useful for data like zip codes, ids and so on. Note, when using mapping definitions, it might make more sense to simply mark the field as not_analyzed.

You can do either of these like the following:

```cs
 //do not analyze the value
 [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed)]
 public Guid DepartmentId;

 //use keyword analyzer
 [ElasticProperty(Analyzer = "keyword")]
 public Guid DepartmentId;
```

Comment: Are you also using your .NET code to create the index? If not, these settings will not be applied...

Comment: @PaigeCook is right on here.  You'll need to re-create your index and add your mapping, and re-index your documents.  If you use the attribute-based approach above, then you will have to call MapFromAttributes() when you are adding the mapping.  Check the docs [here](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/indices/create-indices.html) for details on how to do this.

Comment: Also, I would recommend the `keyword` tokenizer over `not_analyzed`, as GUIDs aren't case-sensitive.  For example, searching for `3F2504E0-4F89-41D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301` should match `3f2504e0-4f89-41d3-9a0c-0305e82c3301`.

Comment: I have updated the code. I have also deleted the index and re-created. But no use. Do I need to provide any settings before indexing/searching?

Comment: Yes, for the Mapping Attributes to be applied to the index, you need to create the index in Elasticsearch using the NEST client. See the link from @GregMarzouka on creating indicies. If you are creating the index outside of NEST, then you will need to setup a custom mapping. Here is an example during index creation -  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#mappings